# How do I use the Salesforce 18 digit id in my custom formula field?

Tags: salesforce-id

So I had a business requirement of creating a certain type of field (I called it Account Link) that is basically a link to an account name or id. This was quite simple and this is how I created it:

```
HYPERLINK('/' +
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name)), Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Id,
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name)), Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Id,
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Parent.Parent.Parent.Name)), Parent.Parent.Parent.Id,
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Parent.Parent.Name)), Parent.Parent.Id,
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Parent.Name)),Parent.Id,
Id))))),
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name)), Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name,
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name)), Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name,
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Parent.Parent.Parent.Name)), Parent.Parent.Parent.Name,
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Parent.Parent.Name)), Parent.Parent.Name,
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Parent.Name)),Parent.Name,
Name))))))
```

The problem is that business now wants to use the 18 digit id instead of 15 and thats where I am stumped. I know salesforce allows to use the CASESAFEID() method but that would be a formula field within a field . In other words, i tried replacing wherever i have Id with CASESAFE(ID)  but it doesnt work. I also made a separate field that  converts the 15 digit id to 18 and then referenced that field name (account_18_id, I called it) and replaced that with wherever I have id in the formula field. But that does not work either because in both cases I get the errir:

```
Error: Compiled formula is too big to execute (14,809 characters). Maximum size is 5,000 characters
```

Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can shrink your formula dramatically by replacing `IF(NOT(ISBLANK(X, X, IF(NOT(ISBLANK, Y, etc))` with `BLANKVALUE(X, BLANKVALUE(Y, etc))`. Once you've done so, that should free up enough characters to wrap the first `BLANKVALUE` call in `CASESAFEID`. You can also save some characters by using `Parent.Id` instead of `ParentId` for all your terminal field paths.

```
HYPERLINK('/' + CASESAFEID(
    BLANKVALUE(Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId,
        BLANKVALUE(Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId,
            BLANKVALUE(Parent.Parent.ParentId,
                BLANKVALUE(Parent.ParentId, ParentId)
            )
        )
    )),
    BLANKVALUE(Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name,
        BLANKVALUE(Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name,
            BLANKVALUE(Parent.Parent.Parent.Name,
                BLANKVALUE(Parent.Parent.Name, Parent.Name)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I tested this in my org, and it compiles to 10,284 characters. CASESAFEID uses a minimum of 2,000 compiled characters by itself.

Answer (score 1):

CASESAFEID is simply too expensive to use in this formula. I wasn't able to get your code to smaller than 10,000 characters, which was optimized as:

```
HYPERLINK(
    '/'+
    CASESAFEID(
        BLANKVALUE(
            Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId,
            BLANKVALUE(
                Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId,
                BLANKVALUE(
                    Parent.Parent.ParentId,
                    BLANKVALUE(
                        Parent.ParentId,
                        BLANKVALUE(
                            ParentId, 
                            Id
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    BLANKVALUE(
        Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name,
        BLANKVALUE(
            Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name,
            BLANKVALUE(
                Parent.Parent.Parent.Name,
                BLANKVALUE(
                    Parent.Parent.Name,
                    BLANKVALUE(
                        Parent.Name,
                        Name
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

You'll want to create a URL field, then use a Workflow Field Update, Process Builder, or a Before Save Flow, and update the URL field with the formula. Unlike these formulas, the Automation Field Updates don't have a compile size limit that I'm aware of, since the value is only used for calculation.